how I can setup vscode for JAVA selenium BDD project?
code to use to for all my projects, any idea how I can setup VSCODE for TESTNG, QAF Gherkin, MAVEN
tried lots of videos and official docs for Java Extension Pack.
Also tried official microsoft documentation....................

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
